# Getting the ID of a meta box

Tags: metabox, id

I'm wanting to change the display title of a meta box when editing a custom post.

I want to try this solution here:

[How to change the title of a Meta Box on a specified Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65989/how-to-change-the-title-of-a-meta-box-on-a-specified-custom-post-type)

Where I'd be removing the meta box and then re-adding it with a modified title. However, I don't have the ID information of my meta boxes and am having trouble finding them. Is there a way to get a list of ID's of meta boxes? I've looked into the global variable `$wp_meta_boxes`, but I couldn't figure out how to list the ID's.

A bit more information: I didn't create the meta boxes originally. I created custom taxonomies for a specific post type, and Wordpress automatically created the meta boxes that allow you to tag those custom taxonomies while editing my custom post.

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-change-the-titles-of-your-wordpress-category-and-tag-meta-boxes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do in order to get the ID of the metabox,

1. In the *Dashboard* where the meta boxed are located, open up the *Screen Options* tab on the upper right corner
2. Open up your [browser's developer tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (ex: Chrome)
3. Use the element selector ([image]) and select the checkbox label that is listed in the *Screen Options*, like so:

[image]

4. The element will be selected and you should see something similar:

[image]

5. For each `<label for=` tag, you will find the ID's of each meta box, for example:

   - `dashboard_right_now`
   - `dashboard_activity`
   - `dashboard_quick_press`
   - `dashboard_primary`
   - `wp_welcome_panel`

From there, you can continue with the code that you found [in a previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65989) with the ID that you need.